# JasperReports Server and data collection from php to report as parameter

Tags: php, cakephp, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to use *JasperReports* with cakephp. The connection between cakephp and *JasperReports Server* works. It generates a header of an excel report. The problem: I want to pass data to loop on in report but I can't because I don't know how to give a data list as parameter and how to loop.

I don't want to use SQL as data source because I have a filter in the page and according to that I want to export only the data filtered by many parameters in the page.

Here's my code i use to create a report:

```
$c = new Jaspersoft\Client\Client(
            "http://localhost:8080/jasperserver",
            "jasperadmin",
            "jasperadmin"
        );
        $info = $c->serverInfo();
        $controls = array(
            'Contract reference' => 'Contract Reference',
            'Type' => __('Type'),
            'Entity' => 'Subsidiary'
        );

        $report = $c->reportService()->runReport('/reports/Contrat_User', 'xlsx', null, null,$controls);
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=contratexport.xlsx');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($report));
        header('Content-Type: application/xml');
        echo $report;
```

Comment: Why not pass the same parameters to a SQL query? Loop is automatically done by Jasper as it iterates in the detail band through every result row.

Comment: okay, in the filter i have around six parameters to filter on like name, address, client,contract and he can sometimes shoose one, is it possible in this case to tell sql query what request to execute because the query is very complexe and it depends on the parameter some time we will use only where contract_id and in another case we will use where contract_id = 9 and client_id=3 so we have many options for sql requests.Thanks

Comment: In that case you could use the $X{IN;$P{IdList};contract_id} function. If you want all records, simply provide a parameter with all ids in it. If someone narrows it down, you can still use $X{} but then only one id will be in it.

Comment: hi thanks for u reply yesterday,i tried to use the function parameter,it worked in jaspersoft and server perfectly when using default value, the problem is when i integrate it in the application it didn't work, and i found a solution is to use a string instead of an array and use the parameter like this in ($P!{contratid}) and it worked.  the problem is the excel is very slow compared to doc and csv. thanks for your help